# Lambda function unable to create file on S3

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have written the following code to be used in AWS Lambda function. The objective is to

1. Fetch data from MSSQL DB
2. Create a file from this data in S3 bucket.
3. Create a file on FTP Server.

This whole thing is working just fine but as soon as I push this code to AWS Lambda, it fails. It is able to fetch the data but not able to create file on S3. Here is the complete code:

```
"use strict";

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var config = require('./config/dev');
var sql = require("mssql");
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var PromiseFtp = require('promise-ftp');
var fs = require('fs');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
        CreateFileOnS3("This is a sample text file created by lambda function", event, context, callback);
};


function CreateFileOnS3(fileData, event, context, callback) {
    const fileName = generateFileName();
    console.log('Sending file to S3...');
    const s3 = new AWS.S3(config.awsCredentials);
    const params = {
        Bucket: config.app.s3Bucket,
        Key: fileName,
        Body: fileData
    };
    s3.upload(params, function (s3Err, data) {
        if (s3Err) {
            console.log('There was an error creating file on S3');
            callback(true, 'There was an error creating file on S3');
        }
        else {
            console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`);
            callback(null, 'File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}');
        }
    });
}

function generateFileName() {
    var _d = new Date(),
        y = _d.getFullYear(),
        m = _d.getMonth() + 1,
        d = _d.getDate();
    return y + '-' + (m < 10 ? '0' + m : m) + '-' + (d < 10 ? '0' + d : d) + '.txt';
}
```

Here is what the CloudWatch log says:

```
10:38:51
START RequestId: 0965c2ef-94a2-439e-b61b-83f17b5ad3d3 Version: $LATEST

10:38:51
2019-04-22T10:38:51.737Z    0965c2ef-94a2-439e-b61b-83f17b5ad3d3
Fetching data from database...

10:38:53
2019-04-22T10:38:53.364Z    0965c2ef-94a2-439e-b61b-83f17b5ad3d3     
Sending file to S3...

10:39:21
END RequestId: 0965c2ef-94a2-439e-b61b-83f17b5ad3d3

10:39:21
REPORT RequestId: 0965c2ef-94a2-439e-b61b-83f17b5ad3d3  Duration: 30030.33 ms   Billed Duration: 30000 ms Memory Size: 512 MB   Max Memory Used: 95 MB

10:39:21
2019-04-22T10:39:21.760Z 0965c2ef-94a2-439e-b61b-83f17b5ad3d3 Task timed out after 30.03 seconds
```

Memory: 2048MB Timeout: 60Sec

**EDIT:** Updated code only sends the string to be created as text file on S3 which is also not working.

Comment: Increase Lambda function timeout to 900 secondes (max), add more checkpoint to your code, then debug by yourself.

Comment: Does the role of your lambda function have permission to create files on S3?

Comment: @Brian the role has administrator permission.

Answer (score 0):

Check the timeout that's set on the lambda script. Increase it to 2 minutes.

Comment: Already tried that option but increasing time doesn't work either.

Comment: function (s3Err, fileData) is the callback function that we get after the upload is completed. There is no problem there if we name the parameters "data" or "fileData".